# How to check if google calendar api request has finished?

Tags: javascript, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

This is a part of the official Google calendar api example. This code executes asynchronously, which means that if I put a function using received data below, it starts before it gets results needed. How to ensure that the request has finished its job and results are ready? Thanks

```
    function listUpcomingEvents() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 10,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var events = resp.items;
      appendPre('Upcoming events:');

      if (events.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var when = event.start.dateTime;
          if (!when) {
            when = event.start.date;
          }
          appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
      }

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Create your own function

```
myEvents(events){
  // console.log(events);
}
```

#### Call it in the request callback

The anonymous function here is the Google Calendar request callback. So when the request has finished, this function is executed.

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {

  [...]

  // Google calendar API request
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    // Google calendar API request has finished
    var events = resp.items;
    appendPre('Upcoming events:');

    if (events.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        var when = event.start.dateTime;
        if (!when) {
          when = event.start.date;
        }
        appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
      }
    } else {
      appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
    }

    // Here, you're function call
    myEvents(events)

  });
}
```